# How to bevel in the opposite direction

Tags: modeling, bevel

I just wondering how I could bevel in the opposite direction and to make it flow with the bevel on the other end, as seen in the picture below.[image]

Comment: I don't understand this part "make it flow with the bevel on the other end". Have you tried pressing **P** to change profile? https://i.imgur.com/73OSdh6.gif

Comment: Yes I have, it wasn't that accurate. @MarkusvonBroady

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Select all of the vertices that you want to move to match the curve
- Enable **edge slide** by typing gg
- Turn *off* **clamping** by typing c
- Turn *on* **even mode** by typing e
- Turn *on* **flipped** by typing f
- Move the vertices to the left.
- press the left mouse button to select the result.

Here are images of the process

Select the vertices:

[image: select the vertices]

Start edge slide.

[image: starting edge slide]

[image: edge slide helpers]

Enable Even mode

[image]

Enable flipped mode

[image]